# Data View Web Part column header filtering

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

On a SharePoint 2007 environment I have a Data View Web Part that merges the contents of 2 document libraries. The "Enable sorting and filtering on column headers" is set to yes. However when I go to use the filter in the column header it only shows items from 1 of the data sources.

```
Source A Column
1
2
4

Source B Column
3
5 

DVWP Column
1
2
3
4
5

DVWP Column Filter Choices
1
2
4
```

How can I get the filter to show data from both sources?

Comment: I've had a lot of trouble with that setting myself. Can you do it in a Content Query Web Part, instead? I've found that much easier to set up for combining lists if it's default settings work for you.

Comment: From what I can understand the Content Web Part will only display items filtered down from a top level source. Unfortunately it does not look as though this can be done because with the 2 form libraries that I am trying to merge do not have any common ground on which a filter can be made (such as a content type).

Comment: Are your libraries on the the same site collection? If so, they share at least one common ancestor and you can use the fields from the Document Library content type for filters in the web part properties. DVWP may work for you, but this may be an alternative. There's a lot on the web about the CQWP, here's one starter article: http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2009/06/08/the-content-query-web-part/

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is syncing external content with native SharePoint list instead of viewing in web parts only. Going this way you have all options of native SharePoint lists available, including view options to group and sort, but also search and change workflows.

More Information:
http://www.layer2.de/en/products/Pages/Cloud-Connector-for-SharePoint-2010-Office365.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have sometimes seen columns not show up depending on how they were created within the list/library. I have a workaround for this issue: If you create the missing column as a site column, then add it to the list/library, it will show up in the filter choices.

Comment: Unfortunately the columns are already site columns. This is due to them being promoted fields from an InfoPath form.